# Log into spotify using python

Tags: python, python-requests, 2captcha

I am trying to log into my spotify account using my username and password using requests and 2captcha. When I run my code, I am returned with b'{"error":"errorInvalidCredentials"}' and am unable to login.

I used my personal login and extract the csrf token from my cookies for the post requests payload.

Wondering if the data in the post request is being passed through correctly.

```
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha
from email import header
import json
import requests
 
s = requests.Session()
 
headers = { 
    'documentLifecycle':'active',
    'frameType':'outermost_frame',
    'initiator':'https://accounts.spotify.com',
    'method':'GET',
    'url':'https://accounts.spotify.com/en/login/?continue=https%3A//www.spotify.com/us/account/overview/&_locale=en-US',
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'sec-ch-ua':'" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="101", "Google Chrome";v="101"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile':'?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform':'"Windows"',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest':'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode':'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site':'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-User':'?1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36',
}
 
r = s.get('https://accounts.spotify.com/en/login/?continue=https%3A//www.spotify.com/us/account/overview/&_locale=en-US', headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
 
print(r.status_code)
print(r.content)
print(r.history)
 
c = r.cookies
csrf = c.items()[1][1]
 
csrf = str(csrf)
 
print(csrf)
 
headers = {
    'documentLifecycle':'active',
    'frameType':'outermost_frame',
    'initiator':'https://accounts.spotify.com',
    'method':'POST',
    'url':'https://accounts.spotify.com/login/password',
    'Accept':'application/json',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Origin':'https://accounts.spotify.com',
    'Referer':'https://accounts.spotify.com/en/login/?continue=https%3A//www.spotify.com/us/account/overview/&_locale=en-US',
    'sec-ch-ua':'" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="101", "Google Chrome";v="101"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile':'?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform':'"Windows"',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest':'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode':'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site':'same-origin',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36',
    'X-CSRF-Token': csrf
}
 
solver = TwoCaptcha('xxxx')
 
try:
    result = solver.recaptcha(
        sitekey="6LfCVLAUAAAAALFwwRnnCJ12DalriUGbj8FW_J39",
        url='https://accounts.spotify.com/',
        version="V3",
        id="100000")
 
except Exception as e:
    print('Error')
 
else:
    print('solved') 
    captcha = result
    print(captcha)
 
print(captcha['code'])
 
username = 'xxxx'
password = 'xxxx'
 
data = {
    'username': username,
    'password': password,
    'remember': 'true',
    'recaptchaToken': captcha['code'],
    'continue': 'https://www.spotify.com/us/account/overview/'
}
 
r = s.post('https://accounts.spotify.com/login/password', json=data, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
 
print(r.status_code)
print(r.content)
```

Comment: depending on what your eventual plan is could you use the Spotify API? https://developer.spotify.com/console/users-profile/

Comment: @AndrewRyan The spotify api doesn't have all the capabilities I need for my project. Ontop of being able to use the functions the spotify api has, I need to be able to access the subscription plan the user has and be able to cancel, upgrade, and downgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at [spotipy](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.19.0/)? This is what I was using when playing around with the spotify API.

The examples from the website:

```py
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

birdy_uri = 'spotify:artist:2WX2uTcsvV5OnS0inACecP'
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials())

results = spotify.artist_albums(birdy_uri, album_type='album')
albums = results['items']
while results['next']:
    results = spotify.next(results)
    albums.extend(results['items'])

for album in albums:
    print(album['name'])
```